# Determine if a language is context free

Tags: intersection, regular-language, context-free-language

Lets say you have a language L and you want to determine if it is context free. Context free languages intersected with regular languages are context free. Is that enough to prove that L is context free?

Meaning,

L intersect P = T Where P is a regular language and T is context free. Does this imply that L is context free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your statement is **not** true. Consider the following counter-example:

`L = {0n1n2n | n > 0}, P = T = Ø`. Clearly we have `L ∩ P = L ∩ Ø = Ø = T`, and `Ø` is both regular and context-free.

Note it is well-known that `L` is not context-free ([see example on p.12 for a sketch proof by pumping lemma](http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afkjm/cs351/handouts/cfg-pumping.pdf)).

Comment: @JohnSmith `L` can be proved to be non context-free by pumping lemma (see the link for reference), `Ø` can be recognised by the empty regular expression, so it is regular. And all regular languages are context-free, so `Ø` is also context-free